# How can i make the splashscreen cover 100% for React native Expo?

Tags: react-native, image, expo, png

How do i make this splashscreen to cover very well? I do not know why it just covers some place and does not cover some places. I am using react native expo.

My App.JS is looking thus

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import OnboardingScreen from "./src/OnboardingScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./src/LoginScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "./src/RegisterScreen";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="OnboardingScreen"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="OnboardingScreen" component={OnboardingScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={RegisterScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I made use of an image which looks like the image below.

[![Screenshot-1684668761.png](https://i.postimg.cc/Mp7QWsRR/Screenshot-1684668761.png)](https://postimg.cc/w1Bv2QwT)

How Can I make this to cover very well without having to show the splash with white background by the left and the right?

Like i said I am using React native expo for this. Kindly help with this.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Please see source code for what I tried above, Kindly help.

Comment: I am supposing your spalshscreen component is OnboardingScreen? So have u played with some css for your logo? can u please show some onboarding screen code

Comment: have you applied "resizeMode": "cover" to img?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the Image component in your question, anyway you probably forgot to set the property `resizeMode="cover"`

docs: [React Native - Image (resizeMode)](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode)

Answer (score 0):

This Issue can be resolved by using the library **react-native-splash-screen**

Link for lib
[Link for library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen)

Link for implementation
[implementation link](https://blog.logrocket.com/splash-screen-react-native/)